# How to open SalesForce using the JWT method?

Tags: python, jwt, salesforce

I have written a python script to make updates to SalesForce. However the issue is that I login to SalesForce using my username and password but this is a problem because my password changes regularly. I realize that I need to use the JWT method to avoid this. According to PyPi all I need to do is use simple salesforce and provide a private key and consumer key but I cannot figure out how to do this. I have made a connected app and associated it with a self signed certificate. Please advise on how I finish setting up this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dedicated user account for this with Profile flag that says password never expires. There would be a license cost, yes - but it'd work OK even if you leave company and the updates done by "Mr Admin" can look better to end users than by "Brian". Do you get any "why have you changed my data!!!" angry emails? ;)

But if you really need the JWT route these should help:

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5
2. https://gist.github.com/booleangate/30d345ecf0617db0ea19c54c7a44d06f (Python example but read the comments, I had to `pip install pyjwt`, not `jwt`)
3. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201636/authentication-using-jwt/201648 (Apex example, 2 versions of code, raw HTTP requests or using built-in JWT libraries)